# downloading a file from SharePoint Online with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell-3.0, csom

I have a requirement to download files from a sharepoint online document library using powershell

I've managed to get to the point where the download should happen but no luck.

I know its something to do with how I am using the stream/writer

any hints would be greatly appreciated

*Edit 
No error messages are thrown just 0 length files in my local Directory

```
$SPClient =  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
$SPRuntime = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

$webUrl =  Read-Host -Prompt "HTTPS URL for your SP Online 2013 site" 
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Email address for logging into that site" 
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Password for $username" -AsSecureString
$folder = "PoSHTest" 
$destination = "C:\\test"

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl) 
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
$web = $ctx.Web
$lists = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($folder)
$query = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery(10000) 
$result = $lists.GetItems($query)
$ctx.Load($Lists)
$ctx.Load($result)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Edited the foreach as per @JNK
foreach ($File in $result) {
         Write-host "Url: $($File["FileRef"]), title: $($File["FileLeafRef"]) "
        $binary = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($ctx,$File["FileRef"])
        $Action = [System.IO.FileMode]::Create 
        $new = $destination + "\\" + $File["FileLeafRef"]
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $new, $Action 
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
```

}

Comment: So when you say "no luck", what's happening exactly?  Is there an error?  Any feedback of any kind?

Comment: Also shouldn't you escape those inner double quotes?

Comment: And I think the ACTUAL issue is your parentheses on the System.IO.FileStream() creation exclude the `Create`.

Comment: You may also need to instantiate the CREATE parameter as a system.io.filemode object, sometimes just passing in a string won't work for those.

Comment: I've made the changes suggested by @JNK Same result. No errors just 0 length files locally. I've also tried System.Net.WebClient  but it seems SharePoint Online needs the SharePoint Client to authenticate.
I think it's something to do with not knowing the file size to download  or not looping over the stream. .. I really am lost

Comment: Maybe this link can help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2012/02/13/10265370.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. AFAIK Sharepoint online works differently.
I've trued to use components from that script already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the CSOM code above likely can be made to work I find it easier to use the web client method.

(from http://soerennielsen.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/use-csom-from-powershell/)

I've used the code below, to retrieve a bunch of files (metadata from CSOM queries) to a folder (using your $result collection, other params should be adjusted a bit):

```
#$siteUrlString site collection url
#$outPath path to export directory


$siteUri = [Uri]$siteUrlString
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.UseDefaultCredentials=$true

if ( -not (Test-Path $outPath) ) {
    New-Item $outPath -Type Directory  | Out-Null
}

$result |% {
    $url = new-object Uri($siteUri, $_["FileRef"])
    $fileName = $_["FileLeafRef"]
    $outFile = Join-Path $outPath $fileName
    Write-Host "Downloading $url to $outFile"

    try{
        $client.DownloadFile( $url, $outFile )      
    }
    catch{
        #one simple retry...
        try{
            $client.DownloadFile( $url, $outFile )      
        }
        catch{
            write-error "Failed to download $url, $_"
        }
    }
}
```

The trick here is the 
    **$client.UseDefaultCredentials=$true**

which will authenticate the webclient for you (as the current user).

Answer (score 8):

You could also utilize [WebClient.DownloadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) by providing [SharePoint Online credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) to download the resource from SharePoint Online as demonstrated below.

### Prerequisites

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) have to be installed on the machine running the script.

### How to download a file in SharePoint Online/O365 in PowerShell

`Download-File.ps1` function:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


 Function Download-File([string]$UserName, [string]$Password,[string]$FileUrl,[string]$DownloadPath)
 {
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Password)) {
      $SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password" -AsSecureString 
    }
    else {
      $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    }
    $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FileUrl)
    $downloadFilePath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($DownloadPath,$fileName)


    $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
    $client.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    $client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
    $client.DownloadFile($FileUrl, $downloadFilePath)
    $client.Dispose()
}
```

Usage

```
Download-File -UserName "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com" -Password "passowrd" -FileUrl https://consoto.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx -DownloadPath "c:\downloads"
```

Comment: Thanks dear..! It saves my day..!!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to download the file successfully with the following relevant code snippet.  You should be able to extend it for your situation.

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$siteUrl = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter web URL"
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter your username"
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$source = "/filepath/sourcefilename.dat" #server relative URL here
$target = "C:/detinationfilename.dat" #URI of the file locally stored

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileInformation] $fileInfo = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File]::OpenBinaryDirect($ctx,$source);
[System.IO.FileStream] $writeStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($target,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create);

$fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo($writeStream);
$writeStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The direct and almost shortest answer to the question is simply:

```
$url = 'https://the.server/path/to/the/file.txt'
$outfile = "$env:userprofile\file.txt"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $outfile -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

This works at least in Powershell 5.1...

Comment: However, I tried this approach aganist sharepoint online, and I wasnt able to authenticate properly. I have described a full approach to download files from sharepoint online

Answer (score 1):

Short an easy approach to download a file from sharepoint online, **using just powershell and sharepoint online url** *( no pnp powershell )*

This approach can also be used **to perform Sharepoint REST queries, with just powershell and sharepoint REST api**

```
# required MS dependencies
# feel free to download them from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038

Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll' -ErrorAction Stop
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll' -ErrorAction Stop

# prepare passwords
$spCredential = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user, $(ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass -Force))
    
# prepare and perform rest api query
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($targetSiteUrl)
$Context.Credentials = $spCredential
    try {
        #this may return an error, but still will finish context setup
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()    
    }
    catch {
        write-host "TODO: fix executeQuery() err 400 bug" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
$AuthenticationCookie = $Context.Credentials.GetAuthenticationCookie($targetSiteUrl, $true)
    
$WebSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$WebSession.Credentials = $Context.Credentials
$WebSession.Cookies.SetCookies($targetSiteUrl, $AuthenticationCookie)
$WebSession.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose")

Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri $spFileUrl -OutFile $outputFilePath -WebSession $WebSession -errorAction Stop
```

Where

- `$outputFilePath` is the target output file in which you want to save the remote file.
- `$targetSiteUrl` is the target sp site url.
- `$spFileUrl` is the "[sharepoint file full url]"
- `$user` plain text sp user email
- `$pass` plain text sp user pass

Comment: Thank you :) This was a lifetime ago for me but I'm 100% sure someone else will find it useful