# What is the best way to download multiple files with know file types from SharePoint using Powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, sharepoint

I've tried several different coding ideas to download multiple files with known file types (*.xlsx) and unknown file types (*.*) from a SharePoint site.  However, everything I've tried so far doesn't work.  Is there a way to do what I found here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varun_malhotra/2012/02/08/sharepoint-2010-powershell-download-all-files-in-document-library-to-network-share-file-share/ but for files only?

I have this working for files that are static in name and location:

```
#Setting Path Locations to files to be copied
$SharePoint = "https://Pig.com/MyPig/Breed.docx"
$Path = "$ScriptPath\$MyPig\$Breed\$($MyPig)_$($Breed).docx"

#Get User Information
$UserName = Read-Host "Enter your username as MyUserName@Pig.com"
$Password = Read-Host "Enter your password" -AsSecureString

#Download Files
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile($SharePoint, $Path)
```

The above code doesn't work when the file name and type is unknown. What suggestions can you give me that I can get working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use your credentials, then this will work...

```
# 'http://sharepointsite.com/sites/Site1/ListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx'
# becomes '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\Site1\ListName'

$destPath = 'D:\Temp\SPDocs'
$spPath = '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\Site1\ListName'

Get-ChildItem -Path '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\Site1\ListName' | Where-Object { $_.name -like 'MS*' } | Copy-Item -Destination $destPath
```

...otherwise, try this...

```
$destPath = 'D:\Temp\SPDocs'
$spPath = '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\Site1\ListName'

net use $spPath $password /USER:$username

Get-ChildItem -Path '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\Site1\ListName' | Where-Object { $_.name -like 'MS*' } | Copy-Item -Destination $destPath

net use $spPath /delete
```

Windows should cache the credentials from the `net use` command

Comment: Do you think I'd still be able to download it without using net use if I've already connected using $WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)? I am running this from a shared drive on a VM.

Comment: I am also needing to have the path changed by customer name as the files I'm trying to download are based on the customer name.# 'http://sharepointsite.com/sites/$Site1/ListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx'
# becomes '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\Site1\ListName'
$Site1 =  Read-Host 'Enter Customer Name'
$destPath = 'D:\Temp\SPDocs'
$spPath = '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\$Site1\ListName'

Get-ChildItem -Path '\\sharepointsite.com\sites\$Site1\ListName' | Where-Object { $_.name -like 'MS*' } | Copy-Item -Destination $destPath

Comment: @Underdog with a web request you'd have a web page to parse. You should be able to use the same creds ($username/$password) in my code and it's simpler to copy items. Please test my 2nd method works for you, if so, I'll update the code to suit your requirements.

Comment: Okay, I tried your second method; added variables username and password without it didn't work.                                                       Code Used:
$user = Read-Host "Enter your username" $username = "$user@MyWeb" $password = Read-Host "Enter your password"  -AsSecureString $destPath = 'C:\Customer\Example\Deliverables'
$spPath = '\\MyWeb.com\opportunities\Directory\Customer' net use $spPath $password /USER:$username Get-ChildItem -Path '\\MyWeb.com\opportunities\Directory\Customer' | Where-Object { $_.name -like 'MS*' } | Copy-Item -Destination $destPath net use $spPath /delete

Comment: The full error is to long to post here, but here's the top part.                            Result: PS C:\Users\cwuser> C:\Customer\networktest.ps1
Enter your username: underwr
Enter your password: *******
net : System error 67 has occurred.
At C:\Customer\networktest.ps1:8 char:1
+ net use $spPath $password /USER:$username
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 67 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 The network name cannot be found.
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path

Comment: Part2: '\\MyWeb.com\opportunities\Directory\Customer' because it does not exist.
At C:\Customer\networktest.ps1:10 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Path '\\MyWeb.com\opportunities\Directory\Customer 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\MyWeb.com\opportunities\Directory\Customer:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
net : The network connection could not be found.
At C:\Customer\networktest.ps1:12 char:1
+ net use $spPath /delete
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified:

Comment: Part3: (The network con...d not be found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.

Comment: You'll probably need to use SharePoint assemblies, which I can't help you with. See this as an example: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/91696/20209 or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18957440/1368849 or this http://www.nikcraik.ca/sharepoint-powershell-script-to-extract-all-documents-and-their-versions/