# Download a specific file from a group in Sharepoint at Office 365 with powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, download, office365, document

I am new to this Powershell / Office365 / SharePoint stuff, so this is why I am asking here for some help. The problem I am working on is this: I am in a group in SharePoint on [Office365](http://portal.office365.com). There is a document shared between several people, which changing stuff in this document. I want to download this document to my local computer on a regular basis.

I thought, the best way to do this is to use PowerShell for this task. But up to now, I could only login into Office365 with PowerShell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Import-Module Msonline
$mycred = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $mycred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $session
Connect-MsolService -Credential $mycred
```

The problem is: What to do now? When I am googling, there are a lot of different scripts, where everyone is using other functions which do not seem to be the one I am looking for. I also didn't found any good tutorial on this topic.

**Edit**

The answer of PhilC helped a little, but there is something missing and there occurred some questions.

Here is the additional stuff, that I added after the part further up:

```
$sharepointURL="https://somesharepoint-my.sharepoint.com/"
$SPOUSer="myuser@email.com"
$SPOPassword="sometestingpassword"

// ...

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client");
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime");
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy");

// ...

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sharepointURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($SPOUser,$SPOPassword);

if (!$ctx.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) {
    Write-Host "Connected to SharePoint Online site: '$sharepointURL'" -ForegroundColor Green
}

Write-Host "Load Web ..."
$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-Host "Load file ..."
$file = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/personal/myuser_email_com/Documents/test1.docx")
$ctx.Load($file)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

But some questions occurred here:

1. Do I need both logins, to Office365 and SharePoint?
2. When I am running this script, I get this error message: `Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Access denied. Sie haben keine Berechtigung, diesen Vorgang auszuführen oder auf diese Ressource zuzugreifen"` It seems, I do not have the rights to perform this operation or I cannot access to this resource. Is there something wrong I am doing? It is a file I created in Office365. Do I need additional rights? BTW, I am not an administrator, who manages the users and so stuff.

An additional note: With the second script, I wanted to create a small example for downloading a file from my documents, before doing the next step and downloading a file from a SharePoint group, which was shared with me.

Comment: I found my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25476651/4872413

Answer (score 1):

This TechNet sample may help: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-SPO-Folder-and-File-e011b05f

Comment: This link helped, indeed. But there are remaining questions. I am going to edit my initial question.