# How to upload and download aspx files from sitepages in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to upload and download aspx files from sitepages in SharePoint online. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: I solved my problem according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866958/downloading-a-file-from-sharepoint-online-with-powershell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it through Rest API: 
[Working with files by using REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest)

Below is a python about how to download page file:

```html
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version
from config import config

# get data from configuration
username = config['sp_user']
password = config['sp_password']
site_name = config['sp_site_name']
base_path = config['sp_base_path']
doc_library = config['sp_doc_library']

authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
site = Site('https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/abc',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)

folder = site.Folder('SitePages')
folder.download_file('mysitepage.aspx', 'mysitepage.aspx')
```

Comment: it would be folder.get_file('mysitepage.aspx')