# Powershell download from sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, download, webclient

Having a bit of a nightmare with this, thought it would be easy...

```
$url = "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/Software/EQk561eOB41GvL0jxV9XgogBwq9B1SH-w2_0Ocwb9CKQNw?e=Up7H11&download=1"
$output = "C:\ProgramData\COMPANY\FILE.zip"
$start_time = Get-Date
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
At line:1 char:1
+ $wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Now I know this works for other repositories I've used, so it seems to be SharePoint. The URL is most certainly public as it does direct download when opened in an incog session in a browser so I'm at a loss as to what's happening. Seems to be some info out there on public links within SharePoint may be the issue.

Anyone have any ideas.

Update: This ended up being a header issue, ended up using fiddler to packet sniff a web header:

```
$url = "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/Software/EQk561eOB41GvL0jxV9XgogBwq9B1SH-w2_0Ocwb9CKQNw?e=Up7H11&download=1"
$output = "C:\ProgramData\COMPANY\FILE.zip"
$start_time = Get-Date
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36")
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

Comment: This is a common task. [What did you search for?](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27Powershell+download+from+sharepoint%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=d7f18ea5528e4806b69f80d60f7fd0d4&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell+download+from+sharepoint%27&sc=7-37&qs=n&sk=&cvid=d7f18ea5528e4806b69f80d60f7fd0d4t). The link is just a search with your post title show options. As well as similar questions on SO, which could make this a duplicate of say this one. [downloading a file from SharePoint Online with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866958/downloading-a-file-from-sharepoint-online-with-powershell)

Comment: Thanks, postanote, I agree it should be a common task indeed. I've reviewed certain elements and searched for similar items, the linked script is for a credentialed user, however, this is a publicly accessible link that does work without credentials.

As an example, the above script works with a google drive public link but not the sharepoint link. Both are direct downloads of a .zip file.

Comment: OK, but the error is pretty specific. You'd only get that when the file being asked for is not from a direct URL. So, URL of this "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/:u:/s/Software/EQk561eOB41GvL0jxV9XgogBwq9B1SH-w2_0Ocwb9CKQNw?e=Up7H11&download=1" --- should be like what is [here](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell). What you have posted would be a link to be clicked, in order for the file behind the link to be retrieved. Since you did not provide the real link, for the reasons only you know, then no one here can check it.out.

Comment: See also ---[1:](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b8a27f9-ae0e-443e-a4a4-8c1cb2ee3429/downloading-files-in-sharepoint-online-powershell) --- [2:](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139309/download-page-from-sharepoint-online-using-powershell) --- [3:](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-get-file.html). You could also open up Chrome, go to the site, inspect the element and do [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-as-powershell/bgpahgbkjdjjlophjonpeoibjmpfgkhj).